# Not Getting Task Changed Emails

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, alert, task-list

I am not getting the task has been changed emails.  I am getting the assigned and reassigned emails.  I have looked at the timerjobs and everything seems to be running and is not disabled.  Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This should be in the Task List settings.

Task List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Email Notification -> Yes

Also, do you have an alert set up to notify on changes?

Comment: Thanks, but I just said I am getting the emails for items assigned and items reassigned, so I did turn that on.  Doesn't the alert XML also include changes for the task list?  I believe it does.  These are not working.